# Typescript and React: How to dynamically infer types from the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic component that I use to build specific tables along the code. Let's call it `GenericTable`. Its workflow looks like this:

[Table Rendering Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIktU.png)

In order to simplify the question, let's say the  `GenericTable` has only two props: `columns` and `rows`.

```
export const Page1 = () => {
return (
    <GenericTable
      columns={page1Columns}
      rows={page1Rows}
    />
  );
};

export const Page2 = () => {
    return (
        <GenericTable
          columns={page2Columns}
          rows={page2Rows}
        />
      );
    };
```

Let's say that the types of the `columns` and `rows` may vary from page to page. For instance, `Page1` may have a table only showing numbers while `Page2` may have a more sophisticated table with strings, numbers and even other components. This way, the `properties` and `types` of the `GenericTable` should look something like this:

```
type GenericTableProps<ColumnType, RowType> {
    columns: ColumnType;
    rows: RowType;
  }
    
  export const GenericTable = <
    ColumnType extends Page1ColumnType | Page2ColumnType,
    RowType extends Page1RowType | Page2RowType
  >(
    props: GenericProps<ColumnType, RowType>
  ) => {
    // build the table here using the columns and rows props
  }
```

The problem here is, since I may have more than just twos pages calling the `GenericTable`, I do not want to hard code the types such as `Page1ColumnType`, `Page1RowType` and so on. How can I dynamically infer the columns and rows type from the page that is passing it?

For example, in case a `Page3` calls in the `GenericTable`, how can it infer that the `ColumnType` will **extend** the `Page3ColumnType` **without hardcoding** it.

Comment: You need to use union for react component props. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgl84N)

Answer (score 0):

COnsider this example:

```js
type Page1ColumnType = {
    tag: 'Page1ColumnType'
}
type Page2ColumnType = {
    tag: 'Page2ColumnType'
}

type Page1RowType = {
    tag: 'Page1RowType'
}

type Page2RowType = {
    tag: 'Page2RowType'
}

type GenericTableProps<ColumnType, RowType> = {
    columns: ColumnType;
    rows: RowType;
}

export const GenericTable = <
    ColumnType extends Page1ColumnType | Page2ColumnType,
    RowType extends Page1RowType | Page2RowType
>(
    props: GenericTableProps<ColumnType, RowType>
) => { }
```

Type signature of `GenericTable` is unsafe, because  `ColumnType` and `RowType` are not related/binded to each other. It means that this call is perfectly valid from typescript point of view:

```js
const result = GenericTable({
    columns: {
        tag: 'Page1ColumnType'
    },
    rows: {
        tag: 'Page2RowType'
    }
})
```

Have you noticed that columns are `Page1` and rows are `Page2`. In order to bind columns and rows, you need to make it as a part of one data structure:

```js
type GenericTableProps<ColumnType, RowType> = {
    columns: ColumnType;
    rows: RowType;
}

type DataStructure =
    | GenericTableProps<Page1ColumnType, Page1RowType>
    | GenericTableProps<Page2ColumnType, Page2RowType>

export const GenericTable = (
    props: DataStructure
) => { }

// ERROR
GenericTable({
    columns: {
        tag: 'Page1ColumnType'
    },
    rows: {
        tag: 'Page2RowType' // wrong value
    }
})

// OK
GenericTable({
    columns: {
        tag: 'Page1ColumnType'
    },
    rows: {
        tag: 'Page1RowType' // ok
    }
})
```

[PLayground](https://tsplay.dev/w8L6Vw)

If you don't want to hardcode all allowed states up front, you still need to some how map types. If you will provide me with expected interface of row and column I try to write generic function, because I don't know the shape of row and column and how they are related between each other